# How can I restrict amount of data that I retrieve using http service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get("https://api.github.com/users")
     .then(function(response) {
         $scope.users = response.data;
     });
```

I want to retrieve only the first 4 users. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you need some flag for server if it support it: $http.get("https://api.github.com/users?limit=4")
if it is not support that then use angular filter:
ng-repeat="user in users|limitTo:4"